# Trigger cloud build on image registry tag

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-build, google-container-registry

I didn't find how I could trigger a cloud build when a docker image is tagged in the google registry.

Right now : 
when code is pushed on master, Cloudbuild builds a docker image, tag it "latest", and deploy it on dev env.

What I want to do : 
deploy it on prod

how I wanted to do it : 
when an image is tagged "prod", a script would update containers in prod environment with the new image
alternatively, this can be triggered by any "prod" tag on githup commit, but I rather keep the registry trigger, because people here are used to it

Is there a way to do it ?

Answer (score 3):

You can [register an event handler which publish a message when something append on gcr](https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/configuring-notifications).

Then, plug a Cloud Function or a Cloud Run on this pubsub message (through a subscription) and perform what you want. The first thing to perform is to filter the event to keep only these which interest you. Indeed, in the PubSub topic **ALL** the events are published.

Then, on the right message, perform what you want (publish in production, log this action in DB/slack channel/email,...)